# How do I speed up video in wax?

Tags: video

I am trying to use [wax](http://www.debugmode.com/wax/) to speed up a video. I do not see an option for this. I searched [google] but all I could find was to turn up the frame rate. I don't see an option for this.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same thing but I know how to change the general frame rate. Just go to
Project->Settings
and change the frame rate (currently 24). For example, I doubled it by setting it to 48.

However, I don't know how to speed up an individual video. I'm editing a stop-motion video so it's a real pain for me as well. I've upped the frame rate to 30 but it may also speed up music/sounds which I don't want.